# Using List.of() in unit tests fails with IncompatibleClassChangeError when run with PowerMockRunner

Tags: java, junit, powermock

Using `List.of()` in Junit tests fails when run with `PowerMockRunner`. This works perfectly when run with `MockitoJUnitRunner`. When we execute the below code

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ListOfTest {

  @Test
  public void test() {
    assertTrue(List.of(1, 2).size() == 2);
  }
}
```

a `IncompatibleClassChangeError` with error message

`java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Method 'java.util.List java.util.List.of(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)' must be InterfaceMethodref constant`

Comment: Any chance you finally found a solution for this?

Comment: nope, still no lick with java 11. Have to give it a try with java 17 as we upgraded java. I switched to `Arrays.asList`

Answer (score -1):

Running JDK11 by any coincidence ?

Powermock issue with JDK11

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: yes we are using JDK 11, Do you have any additional details on why this is not supported, I could find only one related issue in PowerMock bugs which has no comments (https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/1006)